# WPF: How to always have a new row available in a datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am currently using a WPF/Xaml datagrid with a ViewModel and I am having an issue keeping a new empty row at the bottom. I can tab or enter my way and the datagrid creates a new row, but the users are wanting to always have the new row to click into. Is there an easy way to do this? I have tried a few ways and have come up short.

I have CanUserAddRows = true and AutoGenerateColums = false if that helps any.

Comment: When exactly do you want a new row to be added?

Comment: As soon as the current/last row becomes dirty.

Answer (score 1):

Insert a new Item in your ObservableCollection.

Comment: I like the idea, but I am having troubles catching when the current new row becomes dirty.

Comment: @Austin: See my answer then.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `CanUserAddRows` property of the `DataGrid` to `false` and handle the addition of the "new" blank row yourself. Whenever you want a new row, you should add a "blank" object without any properties set on it to your `ObservableCollection<T>` source collection.

The hard part to figure out is probably *when* to add the row. You could for example do it when the user sets a property of the last item in your source collection.

If the type `T` implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, you could subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event of each item that gets added to the source collection and check whether to add a new item in the event handler, e.g.:

```
private void OnItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var dirtyItem = sender as T;
    if (dirtyItem != null && sourceCollection.LastOrDefault() == dirtyItem)
    {
        T newRow = new T();
        newRow.PropertyChanged += OnItemPropertyChanged;
        sourceCollection.Add(t);
    }
}
```